# Convert UTC time to local time zone

Tags: java

I have to convert UTC time into user local time zone. Currently, I have the two parameters one is time in long format and another is time zone name in string format like "(UTC-05:00) Eastern Time (US and Canada), (UTC-06:00) Central Time (US and Canada)" etc.

So now using these two parameters I have to get date time in string format. I am facing the issue while I am trying to convert the date into a string because the SimpleDateFormat.format(...) will convert the date using its default time zone.

Below are the code portion

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
long time = 1490112300000L;
System.out.println("UTC Time "+ convertLongToStringUTC(time));

String EST = "(UTC-05:00) Eastern Time (US and Canada)";
TimeZone  timeZone1 = TimeZone.getTimeZone(EST);
System.out.println("EST "+ convertTimeZone(time, timeZone1));

String CST = "(UTC-06:00) Central Time (US and Canada)";
TimeZone timeZone2 = TimeZone.getTimeZone(CST); 
System.out.println("CST "+ convertTimeZone(time, timeZone2));

String IST =  "IST";
TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone(IST);      
System.out.println("IST "+ convertTimeZone(time, timeZone));
```

}

```
public String convertTimeZone(long time, TimeZone timeZone)
{
Date date = new Date(time);
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
format.setTimeZone(timeZone);
return format.format(date);
}   

public String convertLongToStringUTC(long time)
{
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
String utcTime = sdf.format(new Date(time));
return utcTime;
}
```

Also let me know if we can achieve this using offset ?

Comment: Searching on StackOverflow turns up a lot of useful information.

Comment: You can put a Local object in to `SimpleDateFormat(String pattern, Locale locale)`

Comment: @Yang What does Locale have to do with the Question?

Answer (score 1):

Use this constructor

```
SimpleDateFormat(String pattern, Locale locale)
```

> Constructs a SimpleDateFormat using the given pattern and the default
>   date format symbols for the given locale. Note: This constructor may
>   not support all locales. For full coverage, use the factory methods in
>   the DateFormat class.

[Java Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#SimpleDateFormat%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Locale%29)

Comment: This troublesome class is now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

Answer (score 1):

Using **Java 8** you can do

```
OffsetDateTime dt = Instant.ofEpochMilli(System.currentTimeMillis())
                            .atOffset( ZoneOffset.of("-05:00"));
//In zone id you put the string of the offset you want
```

Comment: In the ZoneId.of("..") can I pass (UTC-06:00) Central Time (US and Canada) ?
or if can pass the offset value then what value we need to pass in case of day light saving

Comment: You should be using `ZoneOffset` there, as `ZoneId` is misleading.

Comment: @BasilBourque you are correct, edited my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
Instant.ofEpochMilli( 1_490_112_300_000L )
       .atOffset( ZoneOffset.of( "-05:00" ) )

Instant.ofEpochMilli( 1_490_112_300_000L )
       .atZone( ZoneId.of( "America/New_York" ) )
```

## Details

The [Answer by Dennis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43076525/642706) is close. I will provide further information.

Your Question is not exactly clear about the inputs. I will assume your long integer number represents a moment in UTC.

An [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) is an number of hours and minutes and seconds before or after [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). In java.time, we represent that with a [`ZoneOffset`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneOffset.html).

While [`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html) technically works (as seen in code by Dennis), that is misleading as a zone is much more than an offset. A zone is a region’s history of various offsets that were in effect at different periods of history. A zone also includes any planned future changes such as [DST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) cutovers coming in the next months.

```
ZoneOffset offset = ZoneOffset.of( 5 , 30 ); // Five-and-a-half hours ahead of UTC.

ZoneOffset offset = ZoneOffset.of( "+05:30" );
```

Tip: Always include the padding zero on the hours. While not always required in various protocols such as ISO 8601, I have seen software systems burp when encountering single-digit hours like `+5:00`.

If you know the intended time zone for certain, use it. A zone is always better than a mere offset as it brings all that historical information of other offsets for the past, present, and future.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" );
```

I am guessing your number is a number of milliseconds since the epoch of `1970-01-01T00:00:00Z`.

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli( 1_490_112_300_000L );
```

The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

You can adjust into a time zone.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z );
```

These issues have been covered many times in Stack Overflow. Hence the down-votes you are collecting (I am guessing). Please search Stack Overflow thoroughly before posting.

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: Thanks Basil for your inputs.

Instant.ofEpochMilli( 1_490_112_300_000L ).atOffset( ZoneOffset.of( "-05:00" ) )

This code portion is not handling the DST time. I don't have parameter for time zone name such as America/Montreal.

Do you have any idea on this ?

Comment: can you look above comments

Comment: @user3467573 I do not understand your comment. Are you saying you expected a DST cutover that took effect at that date-time? Of course there is no DST cutover as you did not specify a time zone. As I explained, DST is defined within a time zone. You specify only an offset-from-UTC. Many places use an offset of five hours behind UTC. There is no way to know from `-05:00` what time zone is in play, and no time zone means no DST.

Comment: I only have the information like timeZone = "UTC-06:00) Central Time (US and Canada)" and long time = 1490112300000L;

So using this how can I get the correct date time in user local time, I havn't any information like region specific such as "Asia/Kolkata"

Comment: @user3467573 (A) Convince your data source to provide true zone names. (B) Map those strings to what you presume is their intended time zone. For example "Central Time (US and Canada)" might fit `America/Chicago`.